# grafana-influxdb get multiple rows for last timestamp

Tags: time-series, influxdb, grafana

I am using telegraf-influxdb-grafana together. But I could not get rows for only last timestamp.
Here is what I am doing;

- Collecting DB statistics(Running queries at that time) with Telegraf(exec plugin).
- Storing output to influxdb
- Trying to monitor running queries over grafana

But I need to get all rows at last timestamp.

Here is what I've tried;

```
> select * from postgresql_running_queries where time=(select max(time) from postgresql_running_queries)
ERR: error parsing query: found SELECT, expected identifier, string, number, bool at line 1, char 54
```

Here is what I want to see;

```
Time                 DB     USER      STATE                QUERY
2017-06-06 14:25.00  mydb   myuser    active               my_query
2017-06-06 14:25.00  mydb   myuser    idle in transaction  my_query2
2017-06-06 14:25.00  mydb2  myuser2   active               my_query3
```

Can any one help me to achive this?
I am open to any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
select last(fieldname) from measurment_name;
```

Query in this format will return last timestamp data from the InfluxDB.

But I am surprised with the fact that you are expecting 3 values for a single timestamp (unless you have different TAG values, refer this documentation [how to store duplicate points](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2//troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-does-influxdb-handle-duplicate-points)). You will a ONLY ONE record for a given timestamp. InfluxDB overwrites previous content if there is another entry for same timestamp, [here is why](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4150).

Your results will be something like (if you don't have different TAG value):

```
Time                 DB     USER      STATE                QUERY
2017-06-06 14:25.00  mydb2  myuser2   active               my_query3
```

EDIT:

Based on comment, my guess is you are using TAGs to differentiate, still above query should work, if not, you may try by adding WHERE clause.

Comment: Actually it is not overwriting. I have metrics from Telegraf which stored in InfluxDB. For example cpu. 16cpu metrics have same timestamp.
[image_for_query](https://ibin.co/3P9LdTprLj5j.png)

Comment: 16 metrics have same timestamp, make sense. But you can't have SAME timestamp twice (Unless you have two different tags).

Comment: Oh thanks, now I got this. But is there any db that we can use with Telegraf and Grafana which similar to InfluxDB? I need to store metrics that have same timestamp(without different tag) and I could get multiple rows at last timestamp.

Comment: There are lot of time series databases, but they work with Grafana, Telegraf etc., I am not sure. You might need to do your own research. Good luck!